# Cannot resolve symbol ViewModelProviders on AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-architecture-components

Hey I'm trying to get my ViewModel working, but no luck so far. 
Android Studio shows error `Cannot resolve symbol 'ViewModelProviders'`.

Every other question I found on this topic was correcting `extends Activity` to `extends AppCompatActivity`, but I am extending the right one. Not sure what I'm missing...
My code is based on [This YouTube video](https://youtu.be/c9-057jC1ZA)

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    TileAdapter.TileAdapterOnClickHandler {


private BaseViewModel viewModel;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //set Toolbar
    Toolbar myToolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);


    //initialize viewModel
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(BaseViewModel.class);
```

**BaseViewModel.java**

```
public class BaseViewModel extends ViewModel {

private Movie[] mMovie;

public void init (Movie[] movies){
    this.mMovie = movies;
}

public Movie[] getMovie() {
    return mMovie;
}
```

Comment: "Cannot resolve symbol" means that either you do not have the `import` statement, or you do but you do not have the dependency in your Gradle setup.

Comment: Check do you have dependecy for **android.arch.lifecycle:extensions** in build.gradle

Comment: Either he is using some library and added the dependency in gradle file so he is able to import ViewModel or he has custom class `ViewModel` under the different package and he is importing it from there

Comment: Didn't have extensions as dependency. Thanks @MuthukrishnanRajendran

Answer (score 221, accepted):

I didn't have both dependencies in my build, hence the problem.

```
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.0"
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.0"
```

Thanks @Muthukrishnan Rajendran

Comment: @Sheler You're answer is correct but the docs is wrong. In the documentation it is specified that ViewModel and LiveDat both are in  implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"

Comment: Hmm this solution has still did not solved my issue. I have implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1' in my app gradle and allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
} Is there something else that needs added?

Comment: I see ViewModelProvider class but it does not have the .of() method. ViewModelProviders is still not defined. I am on a mac if that matters.

Comment: Is there a min sdk or java 8 definition that needs to be added to the project?

Comment: Never mind. Make sure you sync your gradles files if it does not show up.

Comment: @Sheler. Doesn't work for me. By the way my gradle files have this support library : 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'. 
Does that affect?

Comment: @musterjunk this is for ViewModelProviders not ViewModelProvider

Answer (score 114):

If you are using `androidx` you need this:

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0'
```

Comment: For anybody else having this problem, you also need this in your app gradle:
apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'
and this in your android gradle:
classpath "android.arch.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-alpha06"
If you have trouble where to put these things, look in the android-sunflower demo app from google.

Comment: check this link for the latest androidx version https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Comment: What's the stupidity! ViewModelProvider is available without dependency but for ViewModelProviders we need an extra dependency.

Answer (score 32):

> android.arch.lifecycle:extensions is deprecated use

```
def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:$lifecycle_version"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:$lifecycle_version"
```

Create **instance** of viewmodel like this:

> Java

```
Yourclass obj = new ViewModelProvider(context).get(ClassViewModel.class);
```

> Kotlin

```
var obj = ViewModelProvider(context).get(ClassViewModel::class.java)
```

Comment: Good, but the ´owner´ may not be a ´context´, if this is created in a Fragment.

Answer (score 15):

If you are using compiled sdk version 28 or higher you only need to add single dependecy to get `ViewModel` and `LiveData`

```
dependencies {
    //...
    def lifecycle_version = "1.1.1"

    // ViewModel and LiveData
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$lifecycle_version"
}
```

Comment: To know latest version of the `android.arch.lifecycle:extensions` you can search `extensions` in https://maven.google.com/web/index.html and see latest version

Comment: `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions` is deprecated https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle

Answer (score 10):

In my case (Android Studio 3.6.3 ~ 4.1.2), in `AppCompatActivity` to successfully do:

```
MyViewModel myViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
```

it requires both of these:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
```

(alone with `lifecycle-extentions` is not sufficient)

### Update

It seems that you have no longer to include the gradle implementation line (`'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'`) to instantiate `ViewModelProvider`.

Comment: `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions` is deprecated developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle

Answer (score 5):

you should add library in   your project's  build.gradle

def lifecycle_version = "2.0.0"

```
// ViewModel and LiveData
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
```

Answer (score 5):

I solve this problem from [Android official documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle). Add below to `build.grale`

```
def lifecycle_version = "2.0.0"
// ViewModel and LiveData
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
```

Answer (score 4):

In implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0" and up ViewModelProviders is deprecated,use

```
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(BaseViewModel.class);
```

or in Kotlin

```
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(BaseViewModel::class.java);
```

instead of

```
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(BaseViewModel.class);
```

Comment: just the right info that was needed. thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

In the build.gradle file, add these lines in the dependencies block

```
dependencies {
...
def lifecycle_version = "1.1.1"
// ViewModel and LiveData
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$lifecycle_version"
//if not using java 8,use the following line
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$lifecycle_version"
//if using java 8,ignore above line and add the following line
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:common-java8:$lifecycle_version"
...
}
```

[image: Sample Image of build.gradle file]

Answer (score 3):

-'**ViewModelProviders**' is **deprecated** now

- Now alternative

> - In java

`viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(BaseViewModel.class);`

> - In kotlin

`var  viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(BaseViewModel::class.java)`

Refs -
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProviders

Answer (score 2):

Use `androix` libraries

Change

`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'`

to

`implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha03'`

You can use

```
Refactor>Migrate to AndroidX
```

Answer (score 2):

Works fine in my app(java)
before

```java
loginViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, new LoginViewModelFactory())
                .get(LoginViewModel.class);
```

changes to

```java
loginViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this,new LoginViewModelFactory()).get(LoginViewModel.class);
```

hope it could help

Answer (score 2):

In My Case, I am facing below issue i.e:

> ** cannot access androidx.lifecycle.has a default viewmodelprovider factory which is a [image]subclass of your class Name, check your module classpath check your model conflicting dependencies **

I added below dependencies in my **project build.gradle**.

```
def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"

implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:$lifecycle_version"

implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
```

Then I create my class in a module project and I'm facing this issue, then I add these libraries in **module build.gradle** file and the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. None of the other solutions helped me.

I realized that I was using `import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;` instead of `import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;`.

So make sure you are using `import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;`. That is `ViewModelProviders` with an `s`.