# Android studio lint not including all dependencies

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new to Android and decided to create a new project with the default Login Activity template. Without making any change, just outside the box, I get many lintern errors in different java classes. The errors are at the `import` statements and they refer to multiple classes inside the navigation package.

> **NOTE #1** 
> While similar, this question is NOT a duplicate from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49405616/cannot-resolve-symbol-viewmodelproviders-on-appcompatactivity), because in that case they are using `android.arch` instead of `androidx.navigation`, besides they solved it by adding the dependencies (That is not my case, keep reading)
> And this question is also NOT a duplication from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50700030/cannot-resolve-symbol-viewmodelproviders), because that question references a different class (ViewModelProviders, with an *s*).

> **NOTE #2** 
> The application works indeed.
> When running emulator, it compiles and runs normally.

```java
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
```

> **NOTE #3** 
> Classes from other packages inside `androidx` are imported successfully.

So, surely this has something to do with the implementations in the gradle script.
Here it is:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 32
    buildToolsVersion "32.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.memyselfandi.logindroid"
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

}
```

You can see the `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1`.
I also tried adding `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0` and syncing, but it didn't worked.

In any case, since the app is able to compile and run as state in note #2, it should be an android studio issue, but i have no idea what could be wrong there. I already cleaned the project, the cache, restarted the IDE and the PC.
After a little research and by running a gradle task named `lintFix` I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.tools.lint.client.api.Vendor
```

Edit: More information
I tried adding `classpath "com.android.tools.lint:lint:30.2.2"` to the project's gradle script. It throws a different error when :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/tools/lint/model/LintModelModuleLoaderProvider
> com/android/tools/lint/model/LintModelModuleLoaderProvider
```

Comment: Try to invalidate the cache.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: check this https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/invalidate-caches.html

Comment: No luck, same error

Comment: use java based lifecycle library. You have used kotlin based library.

Comment: Where have I defined that? How do I changed it?

Comment: implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.5.1'
 implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1'

These two library. Just remove -ktx